# How to get offset from CustomScrollView inside NestedScrollView with PrimaryScrollController

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `NestedScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar`. The body of the `NestedScrollView` is a widget with a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverList`.

I want to get the offset from the `ScrollController` that is given to the `NestedScrollView` but it only gives me the offset until the `SliverAppBar` is out of view, but after that the `SliverList` continues to scroll but the `ScrollController` doesn't give the offset.

```dart
NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) => SliverAppBar(..),
  body: RefreshIndicator(
    child: CustomScrollView(..),
  ),
)
```

The `CustomScrollView` will automatically use the `PrimaryScrollController` provided by `NestedScrollView`.
When a listener is attached to that scroll view, the listener will be called when the `SliverAppBar` slides into view and out of view until the [`position.extentAfter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollMetrics/extentAfter.html) is equal to `0.0` and then it will not update at all, no matter how far you scroll down because the `extentAfter` always remains at `0.0`.

How can you retrieve the scroll position of the `CustomScrollView` inside of the `NestedScrollView`?

---

### Implementation

It is important that `PrimaryScrollController` is used because the `ScrollController` should have the features of `PrimaryScrollController`. Anyways, in order for the `SliverAppBar` to work, i.e. it scrolling out of view with the content, the `NestedScrollView` `controller` parameter needs to match the `CustomScrollView` `controller` (or `primary`) parameter somehow.

***[Here is a demo](https://dartpad.dev/experimental/embed-new-flutter.html?id=ae17db11763dec46a9164055e28949a9)***.

Any implementation that allows the content to be scrolled with `PrimaryScrollController.of(context)` is fine.
Just note that the `NestedScrollView` is required in order for the `RefreshIndicator` to appear below the `SliverAppBar`.

Comment: Can you provide more details of your implementation? Where are you setting the controller ?

Comment: I am late, and your demo link is now defunct, but if you can post your sample code somewhere again, I'll be glad to help you out. Otherwise, some items: 1. like the previous comment, how are you setting the controller? 2. how are you setting your notification/listener? 3. is it a context issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458289/6668797

Comment: As a side note, don't call .dispose() on the ScrollController that you get from PrimaryScrollController.of(context). The NestedScrollView handles that on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, I can help you!

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: NestendScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool value) {
        return <Widget>[
           SliverAppBar(),
        ];
      },
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              final _scr = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
              _scr.addListener(() {
                if (_scr.position.pixels == _scr.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                  print('At DOWNW!!!');
                }
              });

              return CustomScrollView(
                controller: _scr,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                      context,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                      List.generate(100, (int index) {
                        return Text('ITEM -> $index');
                      }),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you include and explanation of what your code does please.

Comment: I used `NestedScrollView` for hiding `SliverAppBar` (I leave it empty in code) and show `SliverList`. When I scrolled down, I need load more info from another page from backend (do it on listener function of `ScrollController`. Main problem was be is stop propagate scrolling behavior of NestedScrollView if i set controller to any List widget. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You add listener inside build method and never remove it. Red flag

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you will need to attach a `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` to track the offset of your inner `CustomScrollView`

```
NestedScrollView(
  controller: // PrimaryScrollController
  headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) => SliverAppBar(..),
  body: RefreshIndicator(
    child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      child: CustomScrollView(..),
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
        double customPixel = scrollInfo.metrics.pixels; // same as offset
        return false;
      },
    )
  )
)
```

So, as you mentioned, your NestedScrollView controller’s listener will only respond up to the height of the `SliverAppBar`. And once that is out of view, the `ScrollNotification` will kick in and start responding to the `CustomScrollView` scrolling. Accomplished in two separate areas:

1. NestedScrollView's PrimaryScrollController-listener for SliverAppBar
2. CustomScrollView's NotificationListener-ScrollNotification for itself

Note, you could attach another controller/listener to the inner `CustomScrollView`, but that would go against this note: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html

> ```
> return CustomScrollView(
>   // The "controller" and "primary" members should be left
>   // unset, so that the NestedScrollView can control this
>   // inner scroll view.
>   // If the "controller" property is set, then this scroll
>   // view will not be associated with the NestedScrollView.
> ```