# How to handle the ConnectionState of StreamBuilder when typing keyboard using iOS build of flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a login screen using `rxdart library` when typing keyboard dismissing. because of the rebuild the `ConnectionState of StreamBuilder` in iOS build of flutter.

```
Widget handleLogin() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: lgbloc.loginData,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.connectionState);
          if (snapshot.hasError ) {
            isClick = false;
            _controller.reverse();
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), (){snapshot.hasError.toString();});
            return setLoginText();
          }
          else {
            _skLoginModel = snapshot.data;
            if(_skLoginModel != null){
              if (_skLoginModel.user != null){
                isClick = false;
                _controller.reverse();
                initBloc.saveData(_skLoginModel.user);
                return loginFinish();
              }
              else if (_skLoginModel.error != null && _skLoginModel.error.isNotEmpty){
                _controller.reverse();
                Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (){
                  showInSnackBar(_skLoginModel.error);
                  _skLoginModel.error = null;
                  isClick = false;
                });
                return setLoginText();
              }
              else{
                if(isClick){
                  _controller.forward();
                  return setLoading();
                }
                else{
                  _controller.reverse();
                  return setLoginText();
                }
              }
            }
            else {
              _controller.reverse();
              return setLoginText();
            }
          }

        });
  }
```

I expect still keyboard showing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue these days, which got [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071575/open-keyboard-unexpectedly-closes-if-its-textfield-is-in-a-bottomsheet-of-a-name) (here only the Route Problem is shown).

The textfield has some Issues with Routes and Stream Builders, my final solution was to wrap the StreamBuilder into one Widget, which i kept in State. (Like the bottom widget in the example). Then this widget calls depending on the snapshot.data different Widgets.

In these clean widgets (no Streambuilders etc) my TextFields lived.