# Get InheritedWidget parameter in initState

Tags: flutter, dart, state, inherited-widget

i need some help understanding how to obtain data from inherited widget.

I usually get the parameter from my widget directly from the build method using

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
   //THIS METHOD
   var data = StateContainer.of(context).data;

   return Container(child:Text("${data.parameter}"));
  }
```

But this method cant be called from initState since there is no buildContext yet.

I need in the initState method to have that parameter (i call my fetch from server in that and i need to pass that data to my function), so,  how should i do it?

```
@override
void initState() {
 otherData = fetchData(data);
 super.initState();
}
```

I tried using didChangeDipendencies() but it is called every time the view is rebuilt (popping from screen, etc.) so it is not what i want to use and neither the FutureBuilder widget.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, note that you probably *do* want to use `didChangeDependencies`. But you can't just do your call there without any check. You need to wrap it in an `if` first.

A typical `didChangeDependencies` implementation should look similar to:

```dart
Foo foo;

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  final foo = Foo.of(context);
  if (this.foo != foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    foo.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Using such code, `doSomething` will be executed **only** when `foo` changes.

---

Alternatively, if you are lazy and know for sure that your object will never ever change, there's another solution.

To obtain an InheritedWidget, the method typically used is:

```dart
BuildContext context;
InheritedWidget foo = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Foo);
```

and it is this method that cannot be called inside `initState`.

But there's another method that does the same thing:

```dart
BuildContext context;
InheritedWidget foo = context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(Foo)?.widget;
```

The twist is:
- this method can be called inside `initState`
- it won't handle the scenario where the value changed.

So if your value never changes, you can use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

1, If you only need **InheritedWidget** as a Provider of parameter for **Widget**.
You can using on *initState* as bellow:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var data = context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget;
}
```

2, If you need listener to re-render widget when data of **InheritedWidget** change. I suggest you wrapper your **StatefulWidget** insider a **StatelessWidget**,
 parameter of **StatefulWidget** is passed from **StatelessWidget**, when **InheritedWidget** change data, it will notify to **StatelessWidget**, on **StatefulWidget** we will get change on *didChangeDependencies* and you can refresh data.
This is code guide:

```
class WrapperDemoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DemoData data = StateContainer.of(context).data;
    return Container();
  }
}

class ImplementWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  DemoData data;

  ImplementWidget({this.data});

  @override
  _ImplementWidgetState createState() => _ImplementWidgetState();
}

class _ImplementWidgetState extends State<ImplementWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   //TODO Do sth with widget.data
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    //TODO Do change with widget.data
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried Remi's solution but I think the `ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType` method is deprecated now? I couldn't find it.

Used this instead:

```dart
BuildContext context;
InheritedWidget foo = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Foo>()?
```

Comment: Same here. Remi's answer is from 2019, this needs to be updated.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer the solution with `didChangeDependencies` because `Future.delayed` solution is a bit hack, looks unprofessional and unhealthy. However, it works out of the box.

This is the solution I prefer:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

    bool isDataLoaded = false;

    @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (!isDataLoaded) {
            otherData = fetchData(data).then((_){
                this.isDataLoaded = true;
            });
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
...
```

Comment: While better than `Future.delayed`, a boolean misses the point of the life-cycle, that is handling the scenario where the data changes.

Answer (score -2):

You can also get the context in initState, try using a future with duration zero. You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458289/10205629)

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
        //use context here
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          content: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('@todo')
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }, child: Text('OK')),
          ],
        ));
      });
  }
```

i use it to make loading screens using inherited widgets and avoid some global variables