# Future builder - Need Build Context Prior

Tags: flutter, dart, future, builder

My addSteps function require access to the context.  I have a repository object that is stored here.

```
 Future<int> _addSteps() async {
     repository = RepositoryProvider.of<lo.Repository>(context);
     ...
 }
```

The future `_addStepsFuture` is created in `didChangeDependencies`.

```
didChangeDependencies() {
     addStepsFuture = _addSteps();
}
```

Although the context is recived later in the Build call.

```
FutureBuilder<int>(
          future: _addStepsFuture,
)
```

The `BuildContext` is not available until `Build` is called.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Could you add more example code? What exactly are you wanting to do with the the `BuildContext`? `context` should be available inside `didChangeDependencies`. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458289/8213910)

Comment: I have added some more code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `context` in didChangeDependencies since your `RepositoryProvider.of` call is just using `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` under the hood.

But unless you have a different reason for using the `didChangeDependencies` lifecycle hook, you could also try:

```dart
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final repository = RepositoryProvider.of<lo.Repository>(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _addSteps(repository),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Placeholder();
      },
    );
  }

  Future _addSteps(lo.Repository repository) async {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

or

```dart
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _addSteps(context),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Placeholder();
      },
    );
  }

  Future _addSteps(BuildContext context) async {
    final repository = RepositoryProvider.of<lo.Repository>(context);
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the problem

Comment: Its not advised to do this -> future: _addSteps(repository).  The official instructions are -> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. -> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: I see. In that case, your initial code looks correct, no? Is there an error it's throwing? `RepositoryProvider` simply calls the `Provider` [package's `Provider.of<Foo>(context, listen: false`)](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/abb04a1813b3d81098ed38d438cc5562d95ce28f/packages/flutter_bloc/lib/src/repository_provider.dart#L50) which doesn't need a special context (i.e. it doesn't need the context provided passed to `build`) so long as you've provided the repository somewhere above