# How to call ThemeService themeService = Provider.of(context); in the initial state of a scaffold?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. my question is that how do I switch themes in the initial state of my scaffolds? I already have set up a two themes using provider and I call them on button press or set state. but I'm looking for something more convenient as in changing the theme in initial state. here is my theme code using provider

```
class ThemeService with ChangeNotifier {
  static final ThemeData themeA =
      ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black);
  static final ThemeData themeB =
      ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white);

  ThemeData _currentTheme = themeA;

  get currentTheme => _currentTheme;

  switchToThemeA() {
    _currentTheme = themeA;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  switchToThemeB() {
    _currentTheme = themeB;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

every-time I want to change theme I call this

```
ThemeService themeService = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context);
themeService.switchToThemeB();
```

this works fine on button presses and set state but I am unable to call this in initial state. can someone help me?

Comment: You have tried to set this within the `initState` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at this answer for more information: [Flutter get context in initState method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457717/flutter-get-context-in-initstate-method)

Essentially, you can use the `didChangeDependencies` method (which gets called right after `initState`) or, **inside** of `initState`, you could use something like:

```
void initState() {
  ...
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    ThemeService themeService = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context);
  });
  ...
}
```