# How to ensure code is run only once in a widget?

Tags: flutter

I do have a lot of code that looks like
this:

```
bool _somethingFromApiLoaded = false;
Something _somethingFromApi;

loadSomething() async {
  final something = await ServiceProvider.of(context).apiService.getSomething();
  setState(() => _somethingFromApi = something);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (!_somethingFromApiLoaded) {
      loadSomething();
      _somethingFromApiLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

Note how I produce a lot of boilerplate code to ensure `loadSomething` is only called once.

I wonder if there isn't a lifecycle method to do so that I somehow misinterpret. I can't use `initState` because it does not have context.

Comment: Context is available everywhere in a Stateful widget.

Comment: there is solution here you can try.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457717/flutter-get-context-in-initstate-method

Comment: @gegobyte: It results in an error `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<ServiceProvider>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _MyClass.initState() completed.`

@bingcheng45: Hm, that looks like even more boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to a use a **StatefulWidget** and use **initState()** method.

That is the lifecycle you are referring to.

You should try to use a `Future` inside the `initState()`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); // make sure this is called in the beggining

    // your code here runs only once

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
      _somethingFromApi = await ServiceProvider.of(context).apiService.getSomething();
    });

  }
```

As User gegobyte said, `Context` is available in the initState.
But apparently can't be used for everything.

Comment: That does not ensure that some things are initialised on build, the Future runs after the first build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context` in `initState()` by passing it to the widget:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  HomeScreen(this.context);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _somethingFromApiLoaded = false;
  Something _somethingFromApi;

  loadSomething() async {
    final something = await ServiceProvider.of(widget.context).apiService.getSomething();
    setState(() => _somethingFromApi = something);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (!_somethingFromApiLoaded) {
      loadSomething();
      _somethingFromApiLoaded = true;
    }
  }
}
```