# Flutter Navigator.pushNamed with params returns null

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In a named route navigation I need to pass some arguments, but on destination the value is null. Here my code:

```
onSelected: (value){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '${value['namedRoute']}', arguments: '${value['apiUrl']}');
  },
```

On the destination screen I have:

```
class DetailList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String apiUrl;

  DetailList({Key key, @required this.apiUrl,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailList createState() => _DetailList();
}

class _DetailList extends State<DetailList> {
  final Color bgcolor = HexToColor('#ffffff');

  ApiResponse<List<Detail>> detailList;
  int countDetails = 0;

  DetailListBloc _detailListBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('init=${widget.apiUrl}');

    super.initState();
    _detailListBloc = DetailListBloc(widget.apiUrl);
  }
  .....
```

Here the print output is 'init=null'. I do not know where the problem is as I followed [this link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html). Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thank you for all your help. I found [this link](http://%20https://medium.com/better-programming/spotless-routing-and-navigation-in-flutter-995c647b9258) which describes exactly what I was looking for and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you extract the argument, here is how:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('init=${ModalRoute.of<String>(context).settings.arguments}');

    super.initState();
    _detailListBloc = DetailListBloc(widget.apiUrl);
  }
```

see [reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

**Edit:** because context might not be ready instantly in `initState()` and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458289/9142279) you can use:

```
@override
  void initState(){
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){//you can await it if you want
      print('init=${ModalRoute.of<String>(context).settings.arguments}');
      _detailListBloc = DetailListBloc(widget.apiUrl);  
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: ok, but I need the argument in the initState(). Could you please show me where to put this part of code ?

Comment: you can put it anywhere inside the newly pushed widget, i will edit the answer

Comment: This is the error I receive: The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _DetailList.initState() completed.