# Flutter, Futures, Context and Navigator.pop issues

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

Thank you in advance for looking into this problem I'm having issues just doing popping back to a page!

I have this code that works in one widget. It is scanning a QR code

```dart
     @override
     initState() {
      _scan();
      super.initState();
     }

     Future _scan() async {
      barcode = await scanner.scan();
      widget.test();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
```

How would I correctly do it with this other library? Within the callback call the widget.test() and Pop?

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

_captureController.onCapture(
  (data) {
    print('onCapture----$data');

    setState(() {
      _captureText = data;
    });
  },
);
```

Here is a picture of the error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458289/1843853 You can't use the context to get the inherited widget on the initstate. This link gives you some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was this. Instead of calling a function directly in setState(), I flipped a bool.

```dart
bool _popBack = false;

@override
  initState() {
    _captureController.onCapture(
      (data) {
        print('onCapture----$data');
        setState(() {
          _captureText = data;

          if (!_popBack) {
            _popBack = true;
            _popTime();
          }
        });
      },
    );
```

And this worked !

```dart
Future<dynamic> _popTime() async {
    widget.test();
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Don't ask me too many questions on why or how. It worked !