# Why to use Future.delayed in initState()?

Tags: flutter

Why does this example use `Future.delayed` with no duration (actually a zero duration)?

```
void initState() {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration.zero,
      () {
        final Provider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false);
        productProvider.loadValues(widget.product);
      },
    );
```

Comment: you will get a context to use in Provider.of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initState()` does not contain `context` and `Duration.zero= Duration(seconds: 0);`

`initState` calls when this object is inserted into the tree.

> The Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {}) approach is using the behavior of Dart's event queue to delay execution until the next event loop iteration, at which point it is safe to access context since the widget is guaranteed to be built.

You can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64186001/10157127).

You can read more about [delayed-code-execution-in-flutter](https://oleksandrkirichenko.com/blog/delayed-code-execution-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the code inside the **Future.delayed** will be executed after the widget build completes. We use this methodology to build the widget with some pre-loaded data while we send a request to get other data, once we get the data it will be updated. It is best practice for showing loading widgets after the layout frame built. What if we don't use the **Future.delayed** at all? There will be inconsistency within the page you are displaying. That means you are showing the loading widget before the build method renders the widget.

Explanation: Dart has two modes of code execution: "Asynchronous" code execution and **Synchronous** code execution. The event loop prioritizes Synchronous codes first, followed by Asynchronous codes. The build function in the **Statefull** widget is synchronous code that runs on the main isolate/thread, therefore the Asynchronous code **Future.delayed** will wait till the synchronous code "build()" method completes its duty. The code **Future.delayed** will then be performed on the main thread, but it will wait zero seconds; the Future class requires a time, and we simply give it 0 seconds.