# Flutter Cubit InitState

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I am at the begin of my Cubit learning and i tried to create a "Liter-Tracker" with sharedPrefs. Everything works but not the init state. I have to press a Button first because I initialize the drinkValue with 0. I tried to return an Int with the value from shared prefs but this dont work :( May you help me?

This is my cubit:

```
class DrinkCubit extends Cubit<DrinkState> {
  DrinkCubit() : super(DrinkState(drinkValue: 0));


  Future<void> loadCounter() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    state.drinkValue = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
  }


  Future<int> loadInitCounter() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return state.drinkValue = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
  }

}
```

and this my cubit state:

```
class DrinkState {
  int drinkValue;
  int? amount;

  DrinkState({
    required this.drinkValue,

});

}
```

I also tried something like this in my MainPage, how i usually init my state with setState:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of<DrinkCubit>(context).loadCounter();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I strongly advise you to avoid the StatefulWidget when you use BLoC, but it doesn't mean you can't use it at all. Just be careful because `setState()` can rebuild BlocProvider inside the stateful widget.

As for the initialization process, I suggest you use this approach on the BlocProvider.

```dart
class DrinkScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrinkScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => DrinkCubit()..loadCounter(), // Or call other initialization method
      child: DrinkView(),
    );
  }
}
```

This approach works really well if you reuse this screen multiple times, for example, you redirect to `DrinkScreen` every time you want to fill data and you dispose of the screen afterward (`Navigate.pop()`, etc). This way you can automatically initialize the cubit every time you redirect into this screen, you don't need to use StatefulWidget to init the cubit.

Answer (score 0):

Context is not accessible in initstate, try using didChangeDependencies life cycle method [Flutter get context in initState method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457717/flutter-get-context-in-initstate-method)