# how is the best way to manage session and navigation in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have 2 web pages on my proyect

[image]

[image]

I need to manage the user session. If the user is logged it appears the home page, and if the user is not logged it appears the login page.

I am using a provider to check the state of the session

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<LoginGeneralNotifier>(
      builder: (context, appGenaralNotifier, _) {
        return appGenaralNotifier.getLogged()
            ? HomePage()
            : LoginPage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the url does not change after I am logged

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomePageNamedRoute);

This can be done in initState as shown here:
[Flutter Redirect to a page on initState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269909/flutter-redirect-to-a-page-on-initstate)

Answer (score 0):

what I do is

I have created a class where I am keeping all the global variables

there I create a variable `bool loginStatus;`

and create two methods **get** and **set** for handling the value

and whenever login is successful I set the value to true `loginStatus=true;`

and on the new page in `init()` method I am checking the value of variable if value is false then throw the user to login page else continue

```
class GlobalValues{
  static bool loginStatus;


  static void setLoginStatus(bool val) {
    loginStatus = val;
  }

  static bool getLoginStatus() {
    return loginStatus == null ? false : loginStatus;
  }
}
```

on login page if login is successful

`GlobalValues.setLoginStatus(true);`

on other class pages in init method

```
  @override
  void initState() {
     if (GlobalValues.getLoginStatus()) {
       // call your login page class here
       //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(LoginPageNamedRoute);
       Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are highly-frowned upon in the programming world (unless absolutely no other alternatives are available). Use user sessions instead. Check out [FlutterSession](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session). The package adds user session support in Flutter and is easy to use.

```
// Store value to session
await FlutterSession().set("token", myJWTToken);

// Retrieve item from session
dynamic token = await FlutterSession().get("token");
```