# Redirect user from named route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, mobile-development

So I have a similar issue as the person who asked [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269909/flutter-redirect-to-a-page-on-initstate), except with different requirements that none of the answers there help with.

When a user opens the app, I want them to be greeted with the login page if they haven't logged in or the home page (a bottom nav bar view) if they did. I can define this in the `MaterialApp` as follows:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: authProvider.isAuthenticated
      ? '/home'
      : '/login',
  routes: {
    '/home': (_) =>
        ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(
            child: AppBottomNavigationBar(),
            create: (_) => BottomNavigationBarProvider()),
    '/login': (_) => LoginView()
  },
)
```

So far so good. Except I want this to work on the web, and now even though the default screen when a user first opens `myapp.com` is `myapp.com/#/login`, any user can bypass the login screen by simply accessing `myapp.com/#/home`.

Now I tried to redirect the user to the login page in the `initState()` of the bottom navigation bar (and setting the `initialRoute` to be `/home`), but on mobile this has undesirable behaviour.

If I try this:

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  if (!Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).isAuthenticated) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login');
    });
  }
}
```

then simply pressing back will return the user to the home page, again bypassing the login. If I try to use `popAndPushNamed` instead of just pushing, pressing back will open a blank screen (instead of closing the app).

Is there any way to do this correctly so it works on both web and mobile?

Comment: Try `pushReplacementNamed`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`RouteAware`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteAware-class.html) mixin on your widget classes, they will be notified when they are navigated to (or away from). You can use this to check if the user is supposed to be there and to navigate them away if they are not:

To use it, first you need some global instance of [`RouteObserver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) that all your widget classes can access:

```dart
final routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
```

Then you need to register it with your `MaterialApp`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  routeObservers: [routeObserver],
)
```

Then register your widget to the route observer:

```dart
class HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void didPop() {
    // This gets called when this widget gets popped
  }

  void didPopNext() {
    // This gets called when another route gets popped making this widget visible
  }

  void didPush() {
    // This gets called when this widget gets pushed
  }

  void didPushNext() {
    // This gets called with another widget gets pushed making this widget hidden
  }

  ...
}
```

In your case, you can use the `didPush` route to navigate the user to the login page if they get to that page in error:

```dart
void didPush() {
  if (checkLoginStateSomehow() == notLoggedIn) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('login');
  }
}
```