# flutter Navigator in initState, not working

Tags: flutter, dart

i have code like this from the internet, and my is not working:

```
class _StartingAnimationState extends State<StartingAnimation>{

  @override
  void initState() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4),(){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return mainWindow();
    }));
  });
super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SizedBox(height: 300,width: 300, child: Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/login.json")),             
      );
  }
}
```

I got error:

***[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.***

and

***The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.***

I want my program to show animation for some time, and then navigate to other screen

Comment: initState is called before building context, so Navigator.of(context) won't work. Give didChangeDependencies a try.

Comment: thank you, i saw that i second ago, and i change that

Answer (score 2):

You can't push a new route in `initState`. How ever you can register a post frame callback that can run a function.
In you `build` method, before the `return` statement:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4),(){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return mainWindow();
    }));
  });
});

return MaterialApp(
      home: SizedBox(height: 300,width: 300, child: Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/login.json")),
          //home: SizedBox(height: 300,width: 300, child: Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/login.json")),
      );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and time, i resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

i find answer for eanyone who will find this question

answer is:

i didnt put MaterialApp in my main:

```
runApp(MaterialApp(home: StartingAnimation()));
```

and also i saw mistake in my initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4),(){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return mainWindow();
    }));
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why it's not working?**

The MaterialApp configures the top-level Navigator to search for navigation routes in order:

1. For the `/` route, the home property, if non-null, is used.
2. Otherwise, the routes table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
3. Otherwise, `onGenerateRoute` is called, if provided. It should return a
   non-null value for any *valid* route not handled by home and routes.
4. Finally if all else fails `onUnknownRoute` is called.

That's why error comes when the above approach did not follow `Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.`

**Solution!!!**

Wrap `StartingAnimation` with `MaterialApp`

```
runApp(MaterialApp(home: StartingAnimation()));
```

**Note:** This only happens when navigation is done on the `route` widget, if done on other widgets/screens, it will not occur as `MaterialApp` already initialized as everyone added at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solution is hucky:

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
```

Best way was suggested in [Flutter Redirect to a page on initState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269909/flutter-redirect-to-a-page-on-initstate)

```dart
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("login");
});
```